# Is the partition function 5-adically differentiable at 1/24?

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, p-adic-number-theory, integer-partitions

[Ramanujan's congruences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionPCongruences.html), as extended by Watson and Atkin, show that in the $\ell$-adic metric for $\ell\in\{5,7,11\}$, the partition function is **continuous** at $\frac{1}{24}$, having a limit $\lim_{n\to_\ell1/24}p(n)=0$. And for $\ell\neq7$, the speed of convergence is linear, so $p$ is **Lipschitz continuous** at $\frac{1}{24}$.

(I haven't read these proofs, and it's entirely possible that I'm misunderstanding the results. I'm just trying to get a feel for what is known, treating the results as black boxes.)

A natural followup question: Is $p$ also **differentiable** at $\frac{1}{24}$? (Assume a definition of the derivative appropriate to this context.)

Comment: @reuns I really do mean $p(n)$, the function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, where I apply the $\ell$-adic metric to both the domain and the range, so that $\mathbb N$ embeds in $\mathbb Z_\ell$. As the natural number $n$ approaches $1/24$ in $\mathbb Z_\ell$, the natural number $p(n)$ approaches $0$ in $\mathbb Z_\ell$. This is not immediate, either; as far as I can tell, it is the content of Ramanujan's congruences. As for the derivative, if it exists, it should be an element of $\mathbb Q_\ell$. The complex numbers aren't necessarily involved.

Comment: Then this is immediate from [formula 3](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionPCongruences.html), taking a sequence $n_a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_a 24 \equiv 1 \bmod 5^a$ so that $n_a \to 1/24$ in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ and $p(n_a) \to 0$. Then how would you define differentiability of a non-analytic function in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ defined only at certain $5$-adic integers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naively, let $n_1=4, n_2=4+4\cdot 5,n_3=4+4\cdot 5+3\cdot 5^2,\dots$ where $n_k\cdot 24\cong 1 \pmod {5^k}$ and $p(n_k)\to0\;$ $5$-adically.
Then it seems $p(n_k)/(n_k-1/24)\cong \pm1\pmod{5}$ depending on if $k\cong 0,1\pmod4$ or $k\cong2,3\pmod4$. Thus the difference quotient does not approach a limit.